# Angular - Property ' ' does not exist on type ' '

Tags: angular

I'm a beginner to angular and am taking an online course on edx. In one of the tutorial labs, I am learning how to use the `HttpClient`.

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.GitSearchService.gitSearch('angular').then( (response) => {
    alert("Total Libraries Found:" + response.total_count);
   }, (error) => {
    alert("Error: " + error.statusText)
   })
 }
 title = 'app is functional!';
}
```

It says `total_count` does not exist on type unknown, but in one of the imports, I have `"total_count": number`

Comment: show us your `GitSearchService`

Comment: As mentioned in the answer the problem is not with your `total_count` variable its with the `response` that you are getting back.  Your error message says `says total_count does not exist on type unknown` -- the type of `response` object is `unknown` .Since you are using `typescript` so here you need to specify the type of the response that you expect to get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that the `response` variable doesn't have a type.
You can fix that in different ways, some cleaner, some less.

An unclean way, for example, would be to workaround the typing

```
alert("Total Libraries Found:" + response['total_count']);
```

A more clean way would be to provide a type to the response

```
this.GitSearchService.gitSearch('angular')
  .then( (response : MyAwesomeType) => { your code } )
```

in this case, `MyAwesomeType` is expected to be a type that has the property `total_count`